# AWS Glue : AnalysisException: Table or view not found

Tags: aws-glue, apache-hudi

I am trying to create a view out of a dataframe in Glue 4.0 but I am getting the error - AnalysisException: Table or view not found.
The data format for tables in glue database is hudi.

Code -

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)

# Define the Glue Data Catalog database and table names
database_name = "hudi_db"
table4_name = 'd_person'

table4 = glueContext.create_data_frame.from_catalog(
    database=database_name,
    table_name=table4_name,
)

rows = table4.count()
distinct_rows = table4.distinct().count()
print(f"Number of rows in data frame: {rows} and distinct rows are: {distinct_rows}")


table4.createOrReplaceTempView(table4_name + '_glue_view')


custom_sql_query = """
      SELECT count(*)
    FROM d_person_glue_view
"""

# Execute the custom SQL query
result_df = spark.sql(custom_sql_query)
```

Are there any additional configs required for this? What could be the possible reasons that could result in this error?

Thank you.

I have tried the below things -

1. provide your own SparkSession for it to use in the GlueContext constructor.
2. run your sql on the spark_session object of Gluecontext
3. Directly use sparksql instead of creating a dataframe. This works, but I want to load into dataframe first and then create a view.

Comment: Are you sure that the table you are trying to read is in your default Glue Data catalog? It could be in a different/external catalog. If that's the case, you will need to provide a catalogId when you read it and ensure that you have all the required IAM permissions as well

Comment: I am not sure if i totally get your point, but the database where temp table will be created and read from should be same in a session unless I explicitly mention it, right?

Comment: I mean that when you read from the Glue Data Catalog without specifying the `catalogId` parameter, it will use the default/current catalog. However, maybe the database you are trying to read is in another Data catalog. If that is the case, you have to provide the `catalogId` parameter for that 'external' catalog, i.e.: `glueContext.create_data_frame.from_catalog(
    catalogId=<external catalogId>,
    database=database_name,
    table_name=table4_name,
)
 `

Answer (score 0):

1. Following is the way to read Hudi tables in Dataframe from S3 locaton, it works beautifully for me:

```
spark.read.format("hudi").load(S3_basePath).createOrReplaceTempView("test")

res = spark.sql("select * from test")
```

2. When using ["getCatalogSource"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-gluecontext.html#glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-gluecontext-defs-getCatalogSource) for reading non-streaming data sources stored in Glue Data Catalog, kindly use DynamicFrames instead of DataFrames, and then convert the Dynamic Frame into a Spark DataFrame using "toDF()"  if needed. This is because function "getDataFrameFromCatalog()" is designed for AWS [Glue streaming sources.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-gluecontext.html#glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-gluecontext-defs-createDataFrameFromOptions)

Therefore, following solution worked for me:

```
df1 = glueContext.create_data_frame.from_catalog(
    database="hudidb", table_name= "huditable"
)

AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1698763846214 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(
    df1,
    glueContext,
    "AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1698763846214",
)

df2= AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1698763846214.toDF()

df2.createOrReplaceTempView("hudiview")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Here you are reading from the S3 path of the table. If someone has shared hudi tables to me via lakeformation and i want to read from catalog itself, then what can be done?

Comment: added the solution part in answer, please see point 2 to read hudi table from catalog